# Is it possible to limit number of files a non-admin user can upload via the WordPress media library?

Tags: functions, images, uploads, media-library

How can I limit a non-admin user to only be able to upload 6 images at a time in the WordPress library?

I'm trying to limit the number of files a user can upload using the WordPress media library via a frontend form. I've tried implementing the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Code I've Tried**

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');

function limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file) {
    
    // This bit is for the flash uploader
    
    if ($file['type']=='application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
    
        $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        
        if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error']!=0) {
        
            $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
            
            return $file;
        
        } else {
        
            $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
        
        }
        
    }
    
    if( ! is_super_admin() ) {
    
        if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>5)
    
        $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than four (6) image.";
    
    }
    
    return $file;
    
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you edit your questions code block to indent the code? It's difficult to read what you've got when everything has been flattened. Use the edit link underneath the tags to update the question

Comment: @TomJNowell I think the code is formatted properly now.